# If (last modified date = ...?)

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am new to powershell and I am trying to make a script that goes a bit like this:

if (last modified date of the directory is in the last few minutes)

..then print this out

Right now I have

```
 "lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item "C:\Backups").LastWriteTime

 if ($lastModifiedDate = ) {
 write-output "The local backup is complete!"
 }
```

Not sure what I need to have inside the if?
Happy for all the help and tips I can get!

Comment: Reading the help helps ;-)  [about_ComparisonOperators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1)  ... you should read it complete including the examples to learn how to use it.

Comment: With `(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)` you can create a DateTime object pointing to 10 minutes before now. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple version of the task could be something like this:

```
$lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item -Path 'C:\Backups').LastWriteTime
$desiredDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)

if ($lastModifiedDate -gt $desiredDateTime ) {
    'The local backup is complete!'
}
```

It checks if the LastWriteTime is in the last 10 minutes.